# MATLAB - vector script

Tags: matlab, vector

I have recently started learning MatLab, and wrote the following script today as part of my practice to see how we can generate a vector:

```
x = [];
n = 4;
for i = i:n
    x = [x,i^2];
end
x
```

When I run this script I get what I expect, namely the following vector:

```
x = 0 1 4 9 16
```

However, if I run the script a second time right afterwards I only get the following output:

```
x = 16
```

What is the reason for this?  How come I only get the last vector entry as output the second time I run the script, and not the vector in its entirety? If anyone can explain this to me, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: what vector do you try to generate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you forget to initialize `i`.
after first execution `i` is 4 and remains 4.
then you initialize `x` as an empty vector but because `i` is 4 the loop runs only once.

clear your workspace and inspect it before and after first execution.

Comment: Great!  That makes perfect sense.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Beginning with a fresh workspace, `i` will simply be the [complex number](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/i.html) `1i` (as in `x^2=-1`). I imagine you got this warning on the first run:

```
Warning: Colon operands must be real scalars.
```

So the for statement basically loops over `for i = real(1i):4`. Note that `real(1i)=0`.

When you rerun the script again with the variables already initialized (assuming you didn't `clear` the workspace), `i` will refer to a variable containing the last value of `4`, shadowing the builtin function `i` with the same name, and the for-loop executes:

```
x=[];
for i=4:4
    x = [x, i^2]
end
```

which iterates only one time, thus you end up with `x=16`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input.  Appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2):

Is it possibly a simple typo?

> for i = i:n

and should actually mean

```
for i = 1:n
```

as i is (probably) uninitialized in the first run, and therefore 0, it works just fine.
The second time, i is still n (=4), and only runs once.

Also, as a performance-tip: in every iteration of your loop you increase the size of your vector, the more efficient (and more matlaboid) way would be to create the vector with the basevalues first, for example with

```
x = 1:n
```

and then square each value by

```
x = x^2
```

In Matlab, using vector-operations (or matrix-operations on higher dimensions) should be prefered over iterative loop approaches, as it gives matlab the opportunity to do optimised operations. It is also often more readable that way.

Comment: undefined variables will throw an error. `i` here (on first run) refers to the complex number (a builtin function). And colon operator `:` expects real numbers, thus it takes `real(1i)` which is why you get zero the first time

Comment: Legionair:  Thank you very much for your input!  Yes, it was actually a typo on my part.  I should of course have used for i = 1:n

Comment: @Amro: thanks, you are of course correct. its been a while since i worked with matlab ;-)